# Use pt (point) font sizes in summernote instead of px (pixel) sizing

Tags: summernote

I would like summernote to return font sizes in PT rather than PX. Any ideas. I have tried editing summernote.js but cannot find where the list of default font sizes is specified.

Answer (score 0):

use pt rather than px, summernote automatically convert the font size in px.

Example -> if you set font size 36pt rather than 36px, summernote automatically convert 36pt to 48px.

If you use preview code in summernote editor,

```
<p><span style="font-size: 36px;">Hello</span><br/>
<span style="font-size: 36pt;">Hello</span></p>
```

output:
 Hello -> 36px
 Hello -> 48px